# Rotate/pivot 1000 columns to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, pivot, unpivot

I inherited a DB from which I need to extract data in columns that is currently arranged in rows.  The query to retrieve the data is:

```
select distinct 
    LIMSNo, p250.*, p500.*, p750.*, p1000.* 
from 
    results as r
    inner join Points250 as p250 
    on r.resultsid = p250.resultsid and p250.channel = 1
    inner join Points500 as p500 
    on r.resultsid = p500.resultsid and p500.channel = 1
    inner join Points750 as p750 
    on r.resultsid = p750.resultsid and p750.channel = 1
    inner join Points1000 as p1000 
    on r.resultsid = p1000.resultsid and p1000.channel = 1
where 
    r.limsno between '120053698' and '120053704'
```

which produces

```
LIMSNo           P0001              P0002              P0003   ...     P1000  
120053698        251.6667           302.0196           302.2353        305.9608
120053699        291.6667           342.6545           347.9635        353.6236
120053700        243.3333           298.3206           296.7235        299.5342
120053701        308.3333           365.8397           365.4071        368.3206
120053702        315                363.4153           366.6052        373.1695
```

Note that there are 1000 columns (P0001...P1000)

I want to pivot/rotate the data so that I get this output:

```
        120053698        120053699        120053700        120053701        120053702 
P0001   251.6667         291.6667         243.3333         308.3333         315
P0002   302.0196         342.6545         298.3206         365.8397         363.4153
...
P1000   305.9608         353.6236         299.5342         368.3206         373.1695
```

How do I structure the SQL query?  The DB is SQL 2000.

I have tried a number of approaches to this problem.  My latest attempt was:

```
create table #tempCols
(
    ColName nchar(15)
)

insert into #tempCols
select 
    column_name 
from 
    information_schema.columns
where 
    table_name = 'Points250' 
and column_name like 'P%'

insert into #tempCols
select 
    column_name 
from 
    information_schema.columns
where 
    table_name = 'Points500' 
and column_name like 'P%'

insert into #tempCols
select 
    column_name 
from 
    information_schema.columns
where 
    table_name = 'Points750' 
and column_name like 'P%'

insert into #tempCols
select 
    column_name 
from 
    information_schema.columns
where 
    table_name = 'Points1000' 
and column_name like 'P%'

create table #LIMSList
(
    LIMSNumber nchar(9)
)
insert into #LIMSList
select LimsNo from results
where LimsNo between '100030460' and '100030500'

declare @colList varchar(max)
select @colList = COALESCE(@colList + ',' ,'') + ColName from #tempCols

declare @command varchar(max)
set @command = 
'
    select LimsNo, Point, Data
    from (
        select LimsNo, p250.*, p500.*, p750.*, p1000.* 
        from 
            results as r
            inner join Points250 as p250 
            on r.resultsid = p250.resultsid and p250.channel = 1
            inner join Points500 as p500 
            on r.resultsid = p500.resultsid and p500.channel = 1
            inner join Points750 as p750 
            on r.resultsid = p750.resultsid and p750.channel = 1
            inner join Points1000 as p1000 
            on r.resultsid = p1000.resultsid and p1000.channel = 1
        where 
            limsno in (select LimsNo from #LIMSList)) d
            unpivot (Data for Point in (' + @colList + ')) as unpvt
'

print @command

exec(@command)

drop table #tempCols
drop table #LIMSList
```

But the error I get is:

```
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The column 'ResultsID' was specified multiple times for 'd'.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The column 'ResultsID' was specified multiple times for 'unpvt'.
```

Comment: I have tried a number of approaches.  See my edit for my latest attempt.

Comment: Do you need to do the pivot just once, or regularly?  If it's just once, you can place it all in one Excel worksheet, copy the whole dataset, then paste it to another worksheet using `paste special` | `transpose`.

Comment: I suspect that it will be more than once, though not regularly. Thanks for the Excel suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SQL Server 2000 does not have either an `UNPIVOT` or `PIVOT` operator, you will have to use `UNION ALL` for the `UNPIVOT` and then a `CASE` statement for the `PIVOT`.  Here is a dynamic solution that should work:

```
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @rowCount as int = 1,
  @unpivotCount as int = 0,
  @pivotCount as int,
  @unRow as varchar(10) = '',
  @pivotRow as varchar(10) = ''

select c.Name col
into #colsUnpivot
from sys.columns as C
where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
    C.name LIKE 'P%'

set @unpivotCount = (select count(*) from #colsUnpivot)

-- unpivot the data
while @rowCount <= @unpivotCount 
  begin
    set @unRow = (select Top 1 col from #colsUnpivot)

    set @query =' insert into unpivotData (LIMSNo, Val, Col)
                  select LIMSNo, ' + @unRow + ' as val, ''' 
                    + @unRow  + ''' as col
                  from yourtable'

     exec(@query)

     delete from #colsUnpivot where col = @unRow

     if @rowCount <= @unpivotCount 
        set @rowCount = @rowCount + 1
  end

--select * 
--from unpivotData

-- pivot the data 
select distinct LIMSNo
into #colsPivot
from yourtable

set @pivotCount= (select COUNT(*) from #colsPivot) 
-- reset rowcount
set @rowCount = 1
set @query = ''

---- create the CASE string
while @rowCount <= @pivotCount
    begin
        set @pivotRow = (select Top 1 LIMSNo from #colsPivot)

        set @query = @query + ', max(case when LIMSNo = ' + @pivotRow + ' then val end) as ''' + @pivotRow + ''''

        delete from #colsPivot where LIMSNo = @pivotRow

        if @rowCount <= @pivotCount
            begin
                set @rowCount = @rowCount + 1
                print @rowCount
            end
    end

-- add the rest of the SQL Statement
set @query = 'SELECT col ' + @query + ' from dbo.unpivotData group by col'

exec(@query)

delete from dbo.unpivotData

drop table #colsUnpivot
drop table #colspivot
```

I created a table called `UnpivotData` to hold the data for use with in the `PIVOT` process.

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31b7c/5)

Comment: Hi, How to do the same using `pivot` and `unpivot`? I have a similar situation (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683289/transpose-rows-to-columns-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

pivot and unpivot operators are not available in SQL Server 2000. So you have to  pivot and unpivot the data  using other techniques.

I am listing static methods of unpivot and pivot and i hope you can convert it into dynamic solution if you want.

assuming you have inserted the data of your query into a table you can unpivot the data using UNION ALL and insert it into temporary table.

```
SELECT 
*
INTO dbo.temp
FROM 
(
SELECT LIMSNo, P0001 AS [Point],'P0001' AS [ColName] FROM dbo.myTable
UNION ALL 
SELECT LIMSNo, P0002 AS [Point],'P0002' AS [ColName] FROM dbo.myTable
UNION ALL 
SELECT LIMSNo, P0003 AS [Point],'P0003' AS [ColName] FROM dbo.myTable
UNION ALL 
SELECT LIMSNo, P0004 AS [Point],'P0004' AS [ColName] FROM dbo.myTable
....
....
UNION ALL 
SELECT LIMSNo, P1000 AS [Point],'P1000' AS [ColName] FROM dbo.myTable
) AS t
```

then you can pivot the data again

```
SELECT 
ColName
,MAX(CASE LIMSNo WHEN '120053698' THEN [Point] ELSE NULL END ) AS [120053698]
,MAX(CASE LIMSNo WHEN '120053699' THEN [Point] ELSE NULL END ) AS [120053699]
,MAX(CASE LIMSNo WHEN '120053700' THEN [Point] ELSE NULL END ) AS [120053700]
....
....
,MAX(CASE LIMSNo WHEN '120053704' THEN [Point] ELSE NULL END ) AS [120053704]

FROM dbo.temp
GROUP BY ColName
```

Comment: Thanks, @ClearLogic, I'll try to develop a dynamic version of your queries.