# SQL 2000 Pivot for job timeline.

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, pivot

I have a script gaind from a website that creates a table of data i then export to excel. This works great in SQL 2005+ but unfortunately i have 2 legacy servers that i would also like to run this on.

I have tried and tried to get this to work but can not get the data to display in the same way.

SCRIPT:

```
--

****************************************************************************************
-- This script returns a (graphical) timeline for all SQL jobs 
--****************************************************************************************
-- Version: 1.0
-- Author:  Theo Ekelmans
-- Email:   theo@ekelmans.com
-- Date:    2013-01-11
--****************************************************************************************

set nocount on 

declare @Minutes table (DT datetime)
declare @JobNames table (JobName varchar(255))
declare @DT datetime 
declare @StartDT datetime 
declare @EndDT datetime 
declare @Resolution int 
declare @RemoveNonactiveJobs int
declare @IgnoreDisabledJobs int

--***************************************************************************************
-- Set variables
--***************************************************************************************
set @StartDT = getdate() - 1 
set @EndDT = getdate()
set @Resolution = 1 -- Enter the Resolution in minutes
set @RemoveNonactiveJobs = 1 
set @IgnoreDisabledJobs = 1

--***************************************************************************************
-- Pre-run cleanup (just in case)
--***************************************************************************************
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Timeline') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Timeline;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#JobRuntime') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #JobRuntime;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Pivot') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Pivot;

--***************************************************************************************
-- Make a Jobname table 
--***************************************************************************************
insert into @JobNames (JobName)
select  replace(name, ' ', '.') --Replace spaces (they are invalid in XML based pivot lower in the code)
from    msdb.dbo.sysjobs
where   enabled = @IgnoreDisabledJobs
--WHERE NAME = '<dbname>'
--WHERE NAME like '%<partial dbname>%'

--***************************************************************************************
-- Genereate a Datetime table between StartDT and EndDT with x minute Resolution
--***************************************************************************************
set @DT = @StartDT

WHILE @DT < @EndDT
    begin
        insert into @Minutes (DT) values(@DT)

        set @DT= dateadd(mi, @Resolution, @DT)
    end

--***************************************************************************************
-- Create a timeline table by crossjoining the Datetime and Jobnames tables
--***************************************************************************************
select DT, JobName, 0 as Active
into #Timeline
from @Minutes cross join @JobNames

--***************************************************************************************
-- Create the Job Runtime information table
--***************************************************************************************
select  replace(name, ' ', '.') as name --Replace spaces (they are invalid in XML based pivot lower in the code)
        --,step_id
        --,step_name
        ,CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), run_date, 112) + ' ' + STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), run_time), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':'), 120) as SDT
        ,dateadd(   s,
                    ((run_duration/10000)%100 * 3600) + ((run_duration/100)%100 * 60) + run_duration%100 ,
                    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), run_date, 112) + ' ' + STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), run_time), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':'), 120) 
                ) as EDT
        --,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(REPLACE(STR(run_duration, 6), ' ', '0'), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':') AS time(0)) AS Duration
        ,((run_duration/10000)%100 * 3600) + ((run_duration/100)%100 * 60) + run_duration%100 DurationSeconds
into    #JobRuntime
FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobs job 
            left JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory his
                ON his.job_id = job.job_id

where   CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), run_date, 112) + ' ' + STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), run_time), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':'), 120) between @StartDT and @EndDT
and     job.name not in ('Database Mirroring Monitor Job', '<dbname>')
and     step_id = 0 -- step_id = 0 is the entrite job, step_id > 0 is actual step number
--and       ((run_duration/10000)%100 * 3600) + ((run_duration/100)%100 * 60) + run_duration%100 > 1  -- Ignore trivial runtimes
order by SDT

--***************************************************************************************
-- Update the Timeline based on the the Job Runtime information table
--***************************************************************************************
update  #Timeline
set     Active = 1
from    #Timeline inner join #JobRuntime 
on      JobName = Name
and     (
            SDT between dt and dateadd(mi, @Resolution - 1, DT)  -- Start point (added for Resolution support)
        or  
            EDT between dt and dateadd(mi, @Resolution, DT) -- End point (added for Resolution support)
        or  
            DT  between SDT and EDT
        )

--***************************************************************************************
-- Delete all jobs from the Timeline that that had no activity
--***************************************************************************************
if @RemoveNonactiveJobs = 1 
    delete 
    from    #Timeline
    where   JobName in  (   select  Jobname 
                            from    #Timeline
                            group by Jobname
                            having  sum(active) = 0 )

--***************************************************************************************
-- Pivot the Timeline table
--***************************************************************************************
DECLARE @Minutes2 AS TABLE(col2set varchar(250) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
DECLARE @cols AS nvarchar(MAX)
create table #Pivot (col1 varchar(250) null, col2 varchar(250) null, col3 int null)
-- col1 = row, col2 = column, col3 = data

insert  into #Pivot
select  convert(varchar(250), DT, 120), JobName, Active 
from    #Timeline 

-- Make a table with all unique col2 values 
INSERT INTO @Minutes2 
SELECT DISTINCT col2 
FROM #Pivot


SELECT  @cols = REPLACE(  -- Replace the space in the XML path by a comma
                          -- ([c1] [c2] [c3] [c4]) ->  ([c1],[c2],[c3],[c4])
        ( 
            -- Build the IN clause of the PIVOT by concactenating ([c1] [c2] [c3] [c4])
            SELECT  quotename(col2set) AS [data()] 
            FROM    @Minutes2
            ORDER BY col2set 
            FOR XML PATH ('') 
        ), ' ', ',') 



-- Build the pivot statement as a dyanamic sql statement
DECLARE @sql AS nvarchar(MAX)
SET @sql = N'   
                SELECT col1 as DT,' + @cols + N' 
                FROM (SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM #Pivot) AS D
                PIVOT(MAX(col3) FOR col2 IN(' + @cols + N')) AS P
                order by col1'

--***************************************************************************************
-- Output the Timeline table
--***************************************************************************************
EXEC sp_executesql @sql

--***************************************************************************************
-- Cleanup
--***************************************************************************************
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Timeline') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Timeline;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#JobRuntime') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #JobRuntime;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Pivot') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Pivot;
```

The problem occurs in the Pivot the Timeline tablesection of the script as that is not compatable with SQL 2000.

As i have said i have tried almost everything to do this and i am just not experienced enough to solve this problem, i got close but displayed incorrectly.

any help in solving this would be great!!

Comment: ps dont worry about other issues in this script i have slightly modified it to suit my needs but thought you guys should see the original and can run yourselves :)

Comment: Since you are using sql server 2000, you will have to look at using a looping process to get the result.  Take a look at [this question and my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443824/rotate-pivot-1000-columns-to-rows) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844109/rows-to-columns-in-sql-server-2000), they both show a way to do this in SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to answer this myself so thought i would post in case anyone else needs

```
--

****************************************************************************************
-- This script returns a (graphical) timeline for all SQL jobs for use on SQL Server 2000
--****************************************************************************************
-- Version: 2.0
-- Author:  Ryan Wooster
-- Date:    18-6-2013
--****************************************************************************************

set nocount on 

declare @Minutes table (DT datetime)
--declare @JobNames table (JobName varchar(255))
declare @DT datetime 
declare @StartDT varchar(20)
declare @EndDT varchar(20)
declare @Resolution int 
declare @RemoveNonactiveJobs int
declare @IgnoreDisabledJobs int
declare @DSQLT varchar(4000)
declare @DSQL varchar(4000)
declare @Server varchar(20)
--***************************************************************************************
-- Set variables
--***************************************************************************************
set @StartDT = getdate() - 1 
set @EndDT = getdate()
set @Resolution = 1 -- Enter the Resolution in minutes
set @RemoveNonactiveJobs = 1 
set @IgnoreDisabledJobs = 1
set @Server = 'IGSQ03UK'
--***************************************************************************************
-- Pre-run cleanup (just in case)
--***************************************************************************************
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Timeline') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Timeline;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#JobRuntime') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #JobRuntime;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Pivot') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Pivot;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblTLine') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tblTLine;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblTasks') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tblTasks;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#JobNames') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #JobNames;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#JobRuntime') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #JobRuntime;
--***************************************************************************************
--Create Temp Tables for use in Dynamic SQL
--***************************************************************************************
CREATE TABLE #JobNames (JobName varchar(128))
CREATE TABLE #Timeline (DT datetime, JobName varchar(128), Active int)
CREATE TABLE #JobRuntime (name varchar(128), SDT datetime, EDT datetime, DurationSeconds datetime)
--***************************************************************************************
-- Make a Jobname table 
--***************************************************************************************
--'+ @IgnoreDisabledJobs +'
SET @DSQLT='
insert into #JobNames (JobName)
select  replace(name, '' '', ''.'') --Replace spaces (they are invalid in XML based pivot lower in the code)
from    '+ @Server +'.msdb.dbo.sysjobs
where   enabled = 1 
--WHERE NAME = ''<dbname>''
--WHERE NAME like ''%<partial dbname>%'''
--Print @DSQLT
EXEC (@DSQLT) 
--***************************************************************************************
-- Genereate a Datetime table between StartDT and EndDT with x minute Resolution
--***************************************************************************************
set @DT = @StartDT

WHILE @DT < @EndDT
    begin
        insert into @Minutes (DT) values(@DT)

        set @DT= dateadd(mi, @Resolution, @DT)
    end

--***************************************************************************************
-- Create a timeline table by crossjoining the Datetime and Jobnames tables
--***************************************************************************************
insert into #Timeline
select DT, JobName, 0 as Active
from @Minutes cross join #JobNames

--***************************************************************************************
-- Create the Job Runtime information table
--***************************************************************************************
SET @DSQL=
'INSERT into    #JobRuntime
select  replace(name, '' '', ''.'') as name --Replace spaces (they are invalid in XML based pivot lower in the code)
        --,step_id
        --,step_name
        ,CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), run_date, 112) + '' '' + STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(''000000'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), run_time), 6), 5, 0, '':''), 3, 0, '':''), 120) as SDT
        ,dateadd(   s,
                    ((run_duration/10000)%100 * 3600) + ((run_duration/100)%100 * 60) + run_duration%100 ,
                    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), run_date, 112) + '' '' + STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(''000000'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), run_time), 6), 5, 0, '':''), 3, 0, '':''), 120) 
                ) as EDT
        --,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(REPLACE(STR(run_duration, 6), '' '', ''0''), 3, 0, '':''), 6, 0, '':'') AS time(0)) AS Duration
        ,((run_duration/10000)%100 * 3600) + ((run_duration/100)%100 * 60) + run_duration%100 DurationSeconds

FROM    '+ @Server +'.msdb.dbo.sysjobs job 
            left JOIN '+ @Server +'.msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory his
                ON his.job_id = job.job_id

where   CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), run_date, 112) + '' '' + STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(''000000'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), run_time), 6), 5, 0, '':''), 3, 0, '':''), 120) between '''+ @StartDT +''' and '''+ @EndDT +'''
and     job.name not in (''Database Mirroring Monitor Job'', ''<dbname>'')
and     step_id = 0 -- step_id = 0 is the entrite job, step_id > 0 is actual step number
--and       ((run_duration/10000)%100 * 3600) + ((run_duration/100)%100 * 60) + run_duration%100 > 1  -- Ignore trivial runtimes
order by SDT'
EXEC (@DSQL)

--***************************************************************************************
-- Update the Timeline based on the the Job Runtime information table
--***************************************************************************************
update  #Timeline
set     Active = 1
from    #Timeline inner join #JobRuntime 
on      JobName = name
and     (
            SDT between dt and dateadd(mi, @Resolution - 1, DT)  -- Start point (added for Resolution support)
        or  
            EDT between dt and dateadd(mi, @Resolution, DT) -- End point (added for Resolution support)
        or  
            DT  between SDT and EDT
        )

--***************************************************************************************
-- Delete all jobs from the Timeline that that had no activity
--***************************************************************************************
if @RemoveNonactiveJobs = 1 
    delete 
    from    #Timeline
    where   JobName in  (   select  Jobname 
                            from    #Timeline
                            group by Jobname
                            having  sum(active) = 0 )

--***************************************************************************************
-- Build and Pivot the Timeline table
--***************************************************************************************
create table #Pivot (DT varchar(250) null, Name varchar(250) null, Active int null)
-- col1 = row, col2 = column, col3 = data


insert  into #Pivot
select  convert(varchar(250), DT, 120), JobName, Active 
from    #Timeline 


--~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @TaskName nvarchar(100)

SET NOCOUNT ON

CREATE TABLE #tblTLine (
    [DT] varchar(200)
)

CREATE TABLE #tblTasks (
    [Tasks] varchar(200)
)

INSERT INTO #tblTasks (
    [Tasks]
)
select DISTINCT
    Name
from #Pivot 


INSERT INTO #tblTLine (
    [DT]
)
select DISTINCT
    [DT]
from #Pivot 
ORDER BY DT
--WHERE Active = 1

-- Build Table
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR

select DISTINCT
    [Tasks]
from #tblTasks

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @TaskName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE #tblTLine ADD [' + @TaskName + '] nchar(1) NULL'
    EXEC (@SQL)

    SET @SQL = ''

    SET @SQL = 'UPDATE #tblTLine SET [' + @TaskName + '] = ''0'''
    EXEC (@SQL)

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @TaskName

END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

-- Update Table

DECLARE @SQLUpdate nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @Time nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @Name nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @Active nchar(1)


DECLARE curUpdate CURSOR FOR

SELECT 
    [DT],
    [Name],
    [Active]
FROM #Pivot 
WHERE Active = 1

OPEN curUpdate

FETCH NEXT FROM curUpdate INTO @Time, @Name, @Active

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @SQLUpdate = 'UPDATE #tblTLine SET [' + @Name + '] = ''1'' WHERE [DT] = ''' + @Time + ''''
    EXEC (@SQLUpdate)

    FETCH NEXT FROM curUpdate INTO  @Time, @Name, @Active

END

CLOSE curUpdate
DEALLOCATE curUpdate


SET NOCOUNT OFF


--***************************************************************************************
-- Output the Timeline table
--***************************************************************************************
SELECT * FROM #tblTLine

--***************************************************************************************
-- Cleanup
--***************************************************************************************
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Timeline') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Timeline;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#JobRuntime') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #JobRuntime;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Pivot') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Pivot;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblTLine') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tblTLine;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblTasks') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tblTasks;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#JobNames') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #JobNames;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#JobRuntime') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #JobRuntime;
--~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```